# cypress can't find step definitions

Tags: javascript, cypress, cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to set up the `Cypress` project from scratch and I couldn't find out why `feature` files are not able to identify step definitions.

What am I doing wrong?

I am sharing what I have tried:

This is `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "cypressdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.1.4",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.7",
    "cypress": "^12.7.0"
  },
  "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/features/stepDefs"
  }
}
```

This is `index.js`

```
const cucumber = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

This is `cypress.config.js`

```
const {defineConfig} = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            // implement node event listeners here
            // }, specPattern: 'cypress/integration/stepDefs/*.js',
        }, specPattern: 'cypress/integration/features/*.feature',

    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably just need to specify an extension for step definitions,
see [Step definitions](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/cb6f7882870a0be4bffe1de5db580d058f7a15b9/docs/step-definitions.md)

> ```js
> {
>  "stepDefinitions": [
>    "cypress/integration/[filepath]/**/*.{js,ts}",
>    "cypress/integration/[filepath].{js,ts}",
>    "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.{js,ts}",
>  ]
> }
> ```

so **package.json**

```js
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
  "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/features/stepDefs/*.{js,ts}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The step definitions path should be in `package.json`.

If you have folders inside stepdefinitions folder then use `*` like this

`"stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/stepDefinitions/**/",`

If you are using `"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {`
then it would look like this

```
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/integration/stepDefinitions/**/",
  }
```

The name of the Step definitions file need not be the same as your feature file, but it is recommended.